# How to solve kivy window abort problem in python 3.8

Tags: python, kivy

`sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cgl_glew: The specified module could not be found.`
I have just installed kivy on my Python 3.8 it installed succesfully, when I run the file is {VSCODE} the error says:
`CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.`

Comment: Post the full log, but it sounds like kivy isn't actually installed properly. Did you install a version that supports python 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time for me installing pillow helped, which indeed creates the window for kivy,  may be not installed or some issue related to that. First, if you don't have pillow installed please try to install it first and then see if it works!

can use

```
> pip install pillow
```

if this doesn't works please try to uninstall it and again install it using following commands

```
>pip uninstall pillow
>pip install pillow
```

even if this doesn't works!. The actual explanation given on kivy website was, please install all the dependencies manually for windows if you use pip or else use conda prompt which will automatically install all dependencies. so atlast try to do following thing

open anaconda prompt
execute the following command

```
>> conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

This will definitely helps if you have kivy via pip please consider uninstalling by using

```
>pip uninstall kivy
```

Happy Coding :) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to uninstall and install glew:

```
pip uninstall kivy.deps.glew

pip install kivy.deps.glew
```